# Mock/JUnit ApplicationContext getBean through ApplicationContextAware

Tags: java, spring

I have implemented ApplicationContextAware and injected applicationContext in a class. I am trying to test or mock this applicationContext . getBean() but getting a `NullPointerException`

```
@Mock
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Before
public void init()
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    when(applicationContext.getBean("LLL")).thenReturn(mockAppInstance);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the entire test?